What is the deal with the wiring of my deck GFCI outlet?
So one of the GFCI outlets on my deck tripped and wouldn't reset. It was also not anchored to the deck post, so it didn't meet code.
I bought a new GFCI outlet, plus an outdoor rated junction box with mounting hardware and waterproof fittings for the wires. (My assumption was that the GFCI outlet had gone bad. That happens.)
When I took everything apart, I found that there was a second 14/2 wire wired to the load side of the GFCI. That seemed odd, since I don't know of any slaved outlets in my backyard or deck. (There are 2 outlets on the deck and they are both GFCIs.)
The deck was wired by a reputable electrician hired by the contractor, so I assumed the wiring was correct. (I am the original owner of the house and know that nobody else messed with that outlet other than the electrician.) I replaced the junction box and GFCI, wired everything up, and turned on the power. The new GFCI tripped immediately. Hmmm...
Ok, I disconnected the load side and everything worked. So there was a fault on the load side. Time to track that down.
I have a tone emitter that I can clip to wires and use it to trace them. I hooked it to the hot wire that was connected to the load side of the GFCI, and traced it to a big junction box under the deck with a whole lot of wires going into it. (maybe 8 14/2 cables?) The curious thing is that quite a few of the wire pairs were emitting a tone when I put the sensor on them.
After some head-scratching, I determined that the black wire from the load side of the GFCI outlet met 3 other wires in the junction box. One of them was hot! So the outlet was being fed power both from the line side and from the load side of the GFCI. WTF?
I disconnected that whole cluster of wires, hooked up a meter, and proved to myself that one of those black wires was hot when the breaker was on.
Further, I killed the power and ran a pigtail between the white and black GFCI load wires at the junction box, then went up to the outlet and confirmed that there was a short between the white and black. Thus I proved to myself that that wire pair was really the pair that was wired into the GFCI outlet's load side.
As best I can tell the electrician made a mistake and fed both the line and load side of the GFCI outlet to wires that lead to the breaker panel. That seems dangerous. I'm pretty sure it would cause the GFCI outlet to be hot even if you pressed the test button an tripped it, since it would be getting power from the load wire.
I disconnected the black "load side" wire both in the GFCI outlet box and in the junction box, capped it, and closed everything up. Everything is working as expected.
Has anybody else encountered this particular situation?
You'd think by hiring a reputable electrician I'd avoid things like that. However, I've found and fixed numerous wiring problems in my house.

A license means they pass the test.  It does not mean they understand or obey all the rules.  The licensing board will like to know about their work.

I'm a little confused. are you saying that the deck were working for a period of time and then stopped working or are you saying an electrician worked on you deck and then you noticed that the deck receptacles were not working?

Sounds like you're asking for an opinion about a contractor, which would be off topic.

Yep, there are good and bad tradespeople and they have good and bad days. Glad you fixed what you have.

Is that power that was coming in on the LOAD side of the GFCI actually always-hot? I'm wondering if it was switched power and the electrician simply didn't notice since the switch was both off at the time they were there and in a non-obvious place?

All the work to wire my deck was done at the same time by the same electrician.  (This was quite a few years ago.) Everything appeared to be working. I noticed that the GFCI would not reset, and started hunting for the cause.

@ThreePhaseEel (Great handle!) I don't know for sure if the power to the load side was always hot, but I suspect that it was. There are 2 or 3 switches for different deck lights (and a fan). I'm pretty sure they were all off when I found that the LOAD side of the GFCI was hot.

I wasn't asking for opinions about the contractor as much as asking if anybody had encountered this particular wiring curiosity before. I assume homeowners hook up the LINE and LOAD side of GFCI outlets backwards all the time. Having both sides hot was a new on on me though.

I've done a decent amount of wiring and am able to see basic workmanship and attention to detail. This electrician did neat work, and even did things like put caulk on the fittings where wires go into outlet/junction boxes. This mistake seems out of character with what I observed about his work. (The electricians that built my house, on the other hand, were a disaster.)

Also, @ThreePhaseEel, all the wiring for the deck was home-run wired to the panel and wired to new switches put in by the electrician. They didn't tap into any existing circuits/switches. Thus they owned the entire job and didn't have any existing "mystery wiring" to deal with.
